# Symfony router call controller

Tags: symfony

I'm writing my own project and  want to use some of Symfony components. 
I'm implementing Sf Router to my project and I don't understand how to call controller in router.

For ex I have a class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation as Http;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

class AppRouter
{
    public function match() {
        $context = new RequestContext();
        $request = Http\Request::createFromGlobals();
        $context->fromRequest($request);
        $matcher = new UrlMatcher($this->getRoutes(), $context);
        return $matcher->matchRequest($request);
    }

    private function getRoutes() {
        $fileLocator = new FileLocator([__DIR__ . '/../config']);
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($fileLocator);
        $routes = $loader->load('routes.yml');
        return $routes;
    }
}
```

and I have some defined routes in my `routes.yml` so if I trying to go to registred route `match()` method returns to me an array like below:

```
[
  "_controller" => "Controller\\MyController::testAction"
  "_route" => "test"
]
```

So, how now can I call the controller for matched URL? I'm read a documentation but can't understand how should I do this.

Comment: BTW - don't be rude to others here just as you were in the question you deleted unless you want to earn a trip to banned camp.

Comment: [*`"if you what just to spam in comments just f*ck off pls"`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176416/php-error-which-i-can-not-understand#comment85358520_49176416) - I really didn't deserve that, you were totally out of line there man. This from your [now deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49176416/). You can put those words in the outhouse. You think that "pls" makes it "being polite"? wow.

Comment: and stop soaking everyone and be a good member of the community. You come here to get your petty problems fixed and leave; rich.

Answer (score 5):

This is a much more involved question then it might look.

The easiest approach is to simply explode the _controller string, new the controller and call the action.

```
// Untested but I think the syntax is correct
$matched = $router->match();
$parts = explode(':',$matched['_controller']);
$controller = new $parts[0]();
$controller->$parts[2]();
```

Of course there is a great deal of error checking to be added.

The reason I say it can be more complicated is that there is actually a lot you more you can do.  Take a look at the HTTP Component.  HttpKernel::handle($request) which uses a ControllerResolver class to create a controller as well as an ArgumentResolver to handle many of the controller's arguments.  Fun stuff.

[Create Your Own Framework](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html) is an excellent resource.

And the fairly new Symfony Flex approach gives you a bare bones framework which is worth studying as well.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP Kernel handles the Route to Controller invokation. You can find the full documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/http_kernel_controller_resolver.html)

The Controller Resolver and argument resolver will help you to match pretty easily a route to a controller method. This is the easy and robust way in order to get the router up and running on a legacy project without having to invoke the fully-fledge framework.

> Think about it once more: our framework is more robust and more flexible than ever and it still has less than 50 lines of code.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel;

function render_template(Request $request)
{
    extract($request->attributes->all(), EXTR_SKIP);
    ob_start();
    include sprintf(__DIR__.'/../src/pages/%s.php', $_route);

    return new Response(ob_get_clean());
}

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$routes = include __DIR__.'/../src/app.php';

$context = new Routing\RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest($request);
$matcher = new Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

$controllerResolver = new HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver();
$argumentResolver = new HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver();

try {
    $request->attributes->add($matcher->match($request->getPathInfo()));

    $controller = $controllerResolver->getController($request);
    $arguments = $argumentResolver->getArguments($request, $controller);

    $response = call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);
} catch (Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException $exception) {
    $response = new Response('Not Found', 404);
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $response = new Response('An error occurred', 500);
}

$response->send();
```

`

Comment: Good approach! You did my day

Answer (score 0):

My solution for are next:

1. change a little my routes.yml parameters: no class name contain only slash
2. use `call_user_func_array($this->controller, $this->parameters)`